# Loop through an object starting at an index

Tags: javascript

I have an object that is a list of chatrooms, where the keys are chat room names and the value is a reference to the chat room. I want to deliver the rooms to users 50 rooms at a time. But I don't see how this can be done with an object.

Suppose you want to loop through

```
var obj = {
   "a" : 1,
   "b" : 2.
   "c" : 3
}
```

But start at "b", ending up with only "b" and "c" being accessed. Can it be done, including using some kind of map or table?

Comment: You can use an array like `var include = ['b', 'c']` or `var exclude = ['a']` and iterate over array and get value of that key from `obj`.

Comment: `Object.keys()` plus `.slice()`?

Comment: What happens between each "time"? Are you delivering the rooms in some asynchronous function? Some context would help us craft a solution suited to your program, as there several ways to do this

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't rely on objects keys to be sorted. Although most browsers (if not all) keep them sorted.

So if you want to trust browsers, you can add a counter variable and start doing stuff after the counter reached whatever you want. You can get the length of your object using `Object.keys()` (returns an array). Mixing both, you can do this:

```
var object = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3
};

var keys = Object.keys(object);
var counter;

for (counter = 0; counter < keys.length; counter++) {
    if (counter < 1) continue; // Skip until the second element
    console.log(object[keys[counter]]);
}
```

If you don't know the position of the key in advance, you can add a flag variable and activate it when you reach the desired key, like this:

```
var keys = Object.keys(object);
var counter;
var start = false;

for (counter = 0; counter < keys.length; counter++) {
    if (keys[counter] === 'b') start = true;
    if (!start) continue;
    console.log(object[keys[counter]]);
}
```

Comment: You can always `.sort()` it, just to be sure.

Comment: Good idea. But `.sort()` wouldn't work if it's just iterating the object. So I've added another method (using a flag) that would work.

Comment: Yeah, I meant to be sure that the keys array is sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the MDN post regarding the `for...in` loop:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Basically, you have no guarantee as to the order in which the keys inside the object will be iterated over.  So the idea of skipping a certain "index" simply doesn't apply.  I think you need to follow the advice in the comments, and either keep an array of those keys you are interested in, or figure out a way to quickly exclude certain keys as they come up in your loop.

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
var obj = {
   'a' : 1,
   'b' : 2.
   'c' : 3
};
var ignoreItems = ['a'];

for (var key in obj) {
  if (ignoreItems.indexOf(key) === -1) {
    // ADD YOUR CODE HERE
  }
}
```